# How do I know if an element in a syms vector is assigned (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Define a syms vector

```
f = sym('f', [1 100]);
```

Define a syms variable `x`

```
syms x
```

The elements in vector `f` may be accessed and assigned, e.g.,

```
f(i) = x
```

Given any `k`, then how do I know if `f(k)` is assigned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Let `k` be the index of the entry of `f` to be inspected. Then

```
isAssigned = ~isempty(whos(char(f(k))));
```

is `true` (or `1`) if the `k`-th entry of `f` has been assigned and `false` (or `0`) otherwise.

### Long answer

From the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) (boldface added)

> `A = sym('a',[m,n])` creates an `m`-by-`n` symbolic matrix filled with automatically generated elements. **The generated elements do not appear in the MATLAB workspace**.

For example,

```
>> clear all
>> f = sym('f', [1 10])
>> f =
[ f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10]
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  f         1x10              112  sym
```

which indeed shows that `f1`, `f2` etc don't appear in the workspace. However, if you then assign

```
>> syms x;
>> f(3) = x
f =
[ f1, f2, x, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10]
```

the variable `x` of course does appear in the workspace:

```
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  f         1x10              112  sym                
  x         1x1               112  sym
```

So, a way to check if a particular entry of `f` has been assigned is to check for its existence in the workspace using the functional form of [`whos`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html). Compare

```
>> whos('f2') %// produces no output because no variable f2 exists in the workspace
```

and

```
>> whos('x') %// produces output because variable x exists in the workspace
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  x         1x1               112  sym
```

Given the index `k` of the entry of `f` to be inspected, you can automatically generate the corresponding string (`'f2'` or `'x'` in the above example) using `char(f(k))`:

```
>> k = 2;
>> char(f(k))
ans =
f2

>> k = 3;
>> char(f(k))
ans =
x
```

It only remains to assign the output of `whos(char(f(k)))` to a variable, which will be empty if `f(k)` has not been assigned, and non-empty if it has been assigned:

```
>> k = 2;
>> t = whos(char(f(k)))
t = 
0x1 struct array with fields:
    name
    size
    bytes
    class
    global
    sparse
    complex
    nesting
    persistent

>> k = 3;
>> t = whos(char(f(k)))
t = 
          name: 'x'
          size: [1 1]
         bytes: 112
         class: 'sym'
        global: 0
        sparse: 0
       complex: 0
       nesting: [1x1 struct]
    persistent: 0
```

Thus, applying `~isempty` to this `t` produces `true` (`1`) if the `k`-th entry of `f` has been assigned and `false` (`0`) otherwise:

```
>> k = 2;
>> isAssigned = ~isempty(whos(char(f(k))))
isAssigned =
     0

>> k = 3;
>> isAssigned = ~isempty(whos(char(f(k))))
isAssigned =
     1
```

Comment: While I am waiting for the answer, I used an accompanying indicator vector to indicate if the corresponding element in `f` has been assigned. And I think it also works.