# Accessing an element that is within a symbolic matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math

I created a 3x3 matrix in MATLAB, where each element of the matrix is an column vector. I am facing some difficulties when I try to access the element of one of the column vectors within the matrix.

```
syms a b c real

Cube = sym('K', [3,3])

K1_1 = [a; b; c];
K1_2 = [a; b; c];
K1_3 = [a; b; c];
K2_1 = [a; b; c];
K2_2 = [a; b; c];
K2_3 = [a; b; c];
K3_1 = [a; b; c];
K3_2 = [a; b; c];
K3_3 = [a; b; c];

for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        x = Cube(i,j);
        K1_1(3,1) % this does not give an error
        x
        x(3,1) % this gives an error
    end
end
```

Here is the output of the code above:

```
Cube =
 
[ K1_1, K1_2, K1_3]
[ K2_1, K2_2, K2_3]
[ K3_1, K3_2, K3_3]
 
 
ans =
 
c
 
 
x =
 
K1_1
 
Error using sub2ind (line 52)
Out of range subscript.

Error in sym/subsref (line 766)
                R_tilde = sub2ind(size(L), Idx.subs{:});

Error in MainSimFile2 (line 22)
        x(3,1)
```

I successfully set `x` equal to an element of the matrix which is a column vector. However, I get an error when I try to access an element of the column vector.

How can I set up this matrix?

Answer (score 1):

As written in [the document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html?searchHighlight=sym&s_tid=srchtitle_sym_2#description)

> `Cube = sym('K', [3,3])` creates an 3-by-3 symbolic matrix filled with automatically generated elements. The generated elements **do not** appear in the MATLAB workspace.

For example,

```matlab
>> clear all
>> Cube = sym('K', [3,3])
 
Cube =
 
[K1_1, K1_2, K1_3]
[K2_1, K2_2, K2_3]
[K3_1, K3_2, K3_3]
 
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  Cube      3x3                 8  sym
```

In other words, `K1_1` assigned by

```matlab
K1_1 = [a; b; c];
```

is not the same `K1_1` as either in

```
Cube =
 
[ K1_1, K1_2, K1_3]
[ K2_1, K2_2, K2_3]
[ K3_1, K3_2, K3_3]
```

or the one assigned to `x` by

```
x = Cube(i,j);
```

Therefore, this line is actually declaring a new variable `K1_1`.

```
K1_1 = [a; b; c];
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497737/how-do-i-know-if-an-element-in-a-syms-vector-is-assigned-matlab).

Comment: ok thanks! Yes I understand that x is assigned to a new value. In that case what is the best way to create a matrix of vectors?

Comment: It depends on what you are going to use the matrix. You have two sets of symbols here, namely `K` and `a, b, c`. Do you really need all of them?